# How to bold a text in PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, vb6

I'm developing a new function to "my" program. This function is able to write PDF files by the simple way, making a simple text file with some codes of PDF standard.

I'm trying to understand how it works yet, but my first problem is about how to apply bold on some line of my document.

I've already downloaded the PDF REFERENCES GUIDE, but I've not found nothing about it.

Any idea?

Comment: but i cant apply bold on all the text... only on headers and things like this.

Comment: Use a bold font for text which shall appear in bold. Use a normal font otherwise. Use an italics font for text which shall appear in italics.

Comment: You have to switch fonts. Assuming your `/F1` resource is a standard font, while your `/F2` is bold. Then this should work:
`BT /F1 16 70 400 Td (normal)Tj /F2 16 70 380 Td (bold)Tj /F1 12 70 360 Td (text)Tj ET`

Answer (score 4):

PDF is not like HTML where you can apply formatting tags for emphasis. As you've read in the PDF reference, all that you do in PDF is to setup a graphics environment (colours used, fonts used, etc) and then put text on the page.

If you want to have something show in bold, use a font that is bold. If you want to have something show in italic, use a font that is italic.

Older software used dirty tricks to create "bold-alike" text, but the good (and easy) way to do it is to make sure you select the correct font before you start drawing text.

Comment: But i can't change all the text to bold... how can i apply bold only to one word, for example?

Comment: The problem is about how to apply this config only to part of the document. Is possible?

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro *how can i apply bold only to one word, for example* - by **using a different (bold) font for that word only**. And your comments really indicate that you have not yet grasped the complexity of what you are trying to do. **PDF is no mark-up language.** If you do not want to (or don't have the time to) study the PDF specification to understand PDF (merely downloading it does not suffice), use some existing PDF library.

Comment: @mkl is correct. Set regular font, print text. Set bold font, print text that should be in bold. Set regular font, print more text.

Comment: hard is know which parameter i need to change everytime i print the same font configuration setting. I always print some text  like:              4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/Encoding 5 0 R
/BaseFont /Courier-Bold
>>
endobj                                                                i always change only the first number on the object, and print these things before my text.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. What you list here is the object representing the font, this is not the place where this font is used in the page contents. You *must* read the chapter in the PDF specification about page content and how to render text - that's the only thing that will make you understand how to use these fonts to create bold text.

Comment: *everytime i print the same font configuration setting* - so obviously you every time get the same output. Study the spec, and many different PDFs from the wild!